# Can sb. explain why is this exception happening

Tags: java, eclipse, exception

If it doesn't appear change the string to delete (remove) save and try again.
In Eclipse Juno

I tried with new String(), instead of literals and happened the same.

[image]

PrintScreen in the link - http://picbg.net/img.php?file=b44ca20541c93f70.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying the list while you are iterating over it - this does not work. You can try iterating it from back to front using a normal `for` loop (with index, not a `foreach` loop) and remove while iterating back to front.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Iterator`

```
   List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("aaa");
    list.add("bbb");
    list.add("ccc");
    list.add("ccc");
    list.add("ddd");

    Iterator<String> iterator=list.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()){
        if("ddd".equals(iterator.next())){
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(list);
```

Output:

```
    [aaa, bbb, ccc, ccc]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem occured here because you are iterating over the list and at the same time trying to manipulate it which `ArrayList` does not support means

Detecting modification in the collection and parsing the collection is not done synchronously.
This behaviour is called `Fail fast Iterators`.

Example for fail fast iterators are `ArrayList`, `HashSet`.